# Does this identity over {0,1} have any relation to logarithms?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, binary

I was working with Bernoulli Mixture models for a Machine Learning class, and I stumbled across a (to me, surprising) identity.

## Question

The identity in question is

$$\forall x \in \{0,1\}, a,b \in \mathbb{R} : ax + b(1-x) = a^xb^{(1-x)}$$

It is triviably provable by cases.

Interestingly, the form $ax + b(1-x)$ bears striking familiarity to the log form: $\ln(a^xb^{(1-x)}) = x\ln{a} + (1-x)\ln{b}$.

Is there any actual relation, or is this mere mathematical coincidence?

---

#### Background

> Let $x \in \{0,1\}^D$ be a vector of random binary variables. Assume each $x_d$ is drawn from a Bernoulli distribution with mean $p_d$. Let $p \in (0,1)^D$ be the resulting parameters—write an expression for $\Pr(x \mid p)$.

I originally wrote

$$\Pr(x \mid p) = \prod_{d = 1}^D x_dp_d + (1-x_d)(1-p_d)$$

Later, I realized that this was equivalent to

$$\Pr(x \mid p) = \prod_{d=1}^D p_d^{x_d}{(1-p_d)}^{(1-x_d)}$$

The latter plays nicer with log-likelihoods, which is how I came upon it. I pared it down to the 1-$d$ case above.

Comment: Tagging this was hard; I'd appreciate any efforts to pick the right ones.

Comment: It's not specific to $\log$ in the sense that $f(xa+(1-x)b) = x f(a)+(1-x)f(b)$ for any function $f$ (your equality is $f=\log$)